# Как взять данные из sql начиная с одной датой и заканчивая другой?

Tags: python, sqlite3

У sql таблицы такие данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой код на python у меня

```
date_now = "2021-09-25"
date_defor = "2024-09-25"
time_now = "14:17:21"
time_defor = "14:17:27"

get_all_sql = f"""
SELECT * FROM dataframe
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND time BETWEEN ? AND ?
"""

result = cursor.execute(get_all_sql, (date_now, date_defor, time_now, time_defor))
print(result.fetchone())
```

Но мне выводит только одну строчку, а мне бы хотелось все данные в указанном диапазоне

```
(3, 24.14, -10.5, '2023-09-25', '14:17:21', 25.74, 3.49049, 7.8343)
```

Comment: **fetchone()** - возвращает первую запись... наверное, стоит воспользоваться методом **fetchall()**

Comment: Ох спасибо. Это то, что нужно

Comment: @SwaD напишите ответ и я его посчитаю как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода полного набора выборки из sqlite3, необходимо использовать метод **fetchall()**

Пример:

```
result = cursor.execute(get_all_sql, (date_now, date_defor, time_now, time_defor))
print(result.fetchall())
```

Подробнее о данном методе и других, можно ознакомиться в [документации](https://proproprogs.ru/modules/metody-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-iterdump)